# Construct a sequence of real numbers given the subsequential limit values. Identify the lim inf and lim sup.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limsup-and-liminf

[photo of the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Juyfy.jpg)

Also, find a subsequence such that the limit of the subsequence equals the lim sup of the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Take sequence $a_{4n+1}=1, a_{4n+2}=\sqrt{2}, a_{4n+3} = \sqrt{3}, a_{4n+4}=2$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$. Here $limInf(a_n) = 1 = lim(a_{4n+1})$ and $limsup(a_n) = 2 = lim(a_{4n+4})$.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, but what if the set of subsequential limit values is Z (the integers)?

Comment: Take sequence $\{a_n\} = \{0, 0+(1/2), 1+(1/2), (-1)+(1/2), 0+(1/3), 1+(1/3), 2+(1/3), (-1)+(1/3), (-2)+(1/3), 0+(1/4), 1+(1/4), 2+(1/4), 3+(1/4), (-1)+(1/4), (-2)+(1/4), (-3)+(1/4),...\}$